# If a living person had been inside Starman's suit, would the launch have been survivable?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, spacesuits

The spacesuit in the falcon heavy test launch was a genuine test article. Assuming the suit performed nominally could a person have ridden the roadster into space?

Comment: The SpaceX spacesuit is of emergency kind to be used during  the ascent and entry stages (like [Sokol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokol_space_suit) and [ACES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpkin_suit))- "They’re primarily needed in case there’s an emergency scenario during flight; if the spacecraft suddenly depressurizes, the suits will keep the astronauts alive until they can get to safety." - so they have *limited time of work*; and they are for usage *inside the spaceship*. Roadster is in outer space with extreme temperatures from Sun's light, the suit probably can't fully transfer it.

Comment: @osgx the question asks only "...could a person have ridden the roadster into space?"

Comment: The dummy's position in the car was probably not ideal to handle the G-Forces of launch, but worked well as a PR stunt.

Comment: To survive not only a suit is necessary. A life support system is needed with oxygen supply, removement of carbon dioxide and thermal control with cooling if necessary. To handle the G-forces  a special seat may be needed with optimal orientation of the person to the direction of acceleration. The suit is not designed for an EVA, it is to be worn within a capsule.

Comment: Probably the only thing that needs to be answered for this question is whether the seating arrangement and g force profile coupled together would have killed a passenger. I hope someone answers this, I’m curious as well..,

Comment: Before [John Paul Stapp](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Paul_Stapp) started to research, it was believed that 18 g would be lethal. After that the limit was believed to be above 32 g. Stapp survived a test 46.6 g maximum and 25 g for 1.1 seconds. But not all humans would survive what Stapp did.

Comment: @DanSorensen What's not optimal about the position? Wasn't the orientation of the seat roughly the same as what's used on maned flights?

Comment: @kasperd: during launch, a person is situated to be laying down facing up to minimize G-Force impact. The position here was dictated by the position of the car. You may be right but in early photos I saw it appeared the car was not aiming straight up but at an odd angle. No biggie since it was a dummy.

Answer (score 10):

If the suit had been connected to a suitable life support system, the rider would very likely have been ok during the ascent, because:

1. The car appeared undamaged.
2. The suit appeared undamaged.
3. Racecar drivers routinely experience on the order of 5 Gs in similar seats, (albeit for seconds at a time, not minutes). Adding the car AOA to the seat inclination it looks like Starman is leaning back by maybe 60 degrees. Good though not ideal. A G-suit would be nice.
4. The faring is only jettisoned when the residual aerodynamic forces are tiny.

Depending on the helmet, there could be an acoustic problem early on. The F9 user guide puts the sound level at (around) 130dB; the FH is likely louder...